# Gitlab Runner - Same folder (path) for each build

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, cd, runner

I am using gitlab-runner for my CI tasks on centos 7. I have to build the project and then run it.

In my different `xml` and `.sh` files I have different paths which refer to some other files in some directory. For example a file can have path like `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/zzzzz/0/some_folder/run_script.sh`

But each time gitlab-runner starts building the project in a different path like `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/zzzzz/1/`. It causes issues, I have to change all the paths in files.

I want it to build always in the same directory as `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/zzzzz/0/`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Gitlab injects environment variable `CI_PROJECT_DIR` with your project root directory

e.g. `$CI_PROJECT_DIR/script/foo.sh`

Comment: This variable can be used in gitlab-ci.yml script. What I have is different paths in my project code files. So I need to use method to update those paths dynamically.
Instead of giving fixed path like "/home/gitlab-runner/builds/zzzzz/0/some_folder/run_script.sh". 
These paths are in c language scripts or in .xml files. these are not in .yml file.

Comment: These are general shell environment variable, you have access to them from any process not just the yaml file